# Is there a method to reduce two CSS files to one containing unique selectors?

Tags: css, sass

What I have is a large CSS file which was compiled from Sass. I have *some* of the original Sass files, but looking at the source map not all of them.

I'm able to compile the Sass that I *do* have into CSS, but of course some of the style rules are missing.

How can I reduce these two files into only the rules that are unique to the original? I would like to be able to do that so that I can include that CSS with the source Sass I have on hand to speed up future development.

Comment: You have one CSS which is built from a set of SASS files. You have some but not all SASS files. You mention "..these two files". Can you please clarify.

Comment: The original complete CSS file, and the CSS file that I can compile from my incomplete Sass.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

- take original CSS and convert it to Sass by changing extension to `.scss`
- if original CSS is minifed use something like [CSS Formatter](https://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/) to get readable code
- name it something like `legacy` and import first in your master Sass file
- use [nanocss](http://cssnano.co/) in your build process to dedupe duplicate styles (make sure [discard-duplicates](https://github.com/ben-eb/cssnano/tree/master/packages/postcss-discard-duplicates) plugin is enabled)

optional: enable dedupe only for production build since it slows down CSS generation

drawbacks:

- if changing properties on existing classes in Sass dedupe will not match against legacy and you end up with almost-duplicates - to prevent that, I would manually go into `legacy` to delete old classes when changing them in sass partials

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input you should do following "backwards-engineering":

1) Compare you CSS files in a diff-program, e.g. diffchecker.com (let us call your files: file1.css and file2.css).

2) The diff-program will mark duplicate areas with color.

3) Decide which file to update and remove the duplicates, in that file.

Note!. This method will only solve if you have duplicated text blocks in your CSS files. It will not solve to "clean & improve" e.g. if you have spreadout "duplicate" information.